# Assigning variable OnClick random action

Tags: javascript

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var Rand2 = Rand1;

while ( Rand2 == Rand1 ){
    var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
}
var step1 = Rand1;
var step2 = Rand2;

function moveto(step1, step2) {
    var w = $(document).width();
    $('#full').animate({
        left: -(step1*w)
    },  {
    duration: 3000,
    });
}

//what element is this supposed to be?
class="img bg-img1" OnClick="moveto('1');">
```

My problem is: I need to assign the random number given by Rand1 into the OnClick="moveto('Rand1');  how do i do that ?

Comment: That is a div donno why it didn't let me copy it

Comment: As a side note, you may be interested in a `do while` loop, so that you don't have to write the random generation twice, but only inside the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/jNDst/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and remove the onclick from your inline button/element: http://jsfiddle.net/GApnw/

```
function randomNumbers() {
    var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    var Rand2 = Rand1;
    while (Rand2 == Rand1) {
        var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    }
    return [Rand1, Rand2];
}

function moveto(step1, step2) {
    var w = $(document).width();
    $('#full').animate({
        left: -(step1 * w)
    }, {
        duration: 3000,
    });
    alert(step1 + " " + step2);
}

$(function(){
    $(".img").click(function(){
        var randomNum = randomNumbers();
        moveto(randomNum[0], randomNum[1]);
    });
});
```

Or do the call to get the RandomNumbers within your moveto, if you don't give numbers elsewhere.

Comment: Then you can just change `moveto(randomNum[0], randomNum[1]); ` to `moveto(randomNum[0]);`, if you need 2 numbers, the `randomNumbers` function returns an array of 2 numbers, you can just use index 0.

Comment: Remove the `alert(step1 + " " + step2);` from the `moveto` function, the `undefined` is because you are not passing a `step2` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm assuming `Rand1` is declared in the global context, as it looks like it would be from the code in your question. If that's the case, why do you need to pass it into the event handler? It would be accessible from the event handler function anyway:

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
function moveto() {
    //Rand1 is accessible here
}
```

Secondly, it appears that you're using jQuery inside your `moveto` function, so why not use jQuery to attach the event listener as well, instead of doing it inline:

```
$(".bg-img1").click(moveto);
```